Vercel Not behaving as expected
My next app isn't behaving as expected on Vercel but works fine on Netilf. How it is possible ??
My app working perfectly.
Let me explain the code.
I have a form that creates a post and post it on MongoDB atlas. data updated perfectly and redirected the page to the explore page. but on the explore page updated data is not coming from the data.
I use a polling method to get data from DB.

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/thought",{cache:"no-store"});
    const data = await response.json();
    const sortedPosts = data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.createAt) - new Date(a.createAt));
    setPosts(sortedPosts);
    console.log(sortedPosts);
  };

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, 3500);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);

}, []);

However, API perfectly fetches data every 3.5 seconds.
Am I a mistake somewhere?
I am expecting that my app behaving as expected on vercel.
